# Making a SVG Text draggable using d3.js

Tags: jquery-ui, svg, drag-and-drop, d3.js

I want to make a text in a d3 visualisation draggable for use in an editor. I started to play with on e of the examples (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550). When i add a dragbeheavier to the text element, i can tell from the ChromeDevTools that somthing gets dragged but there is no visual representation af that drag. I also tried to do it using JQuery UI what didn't worked either. What do i miss and is it even possible to do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [drag.behaviour](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#wiki-drag) to add drag events to elements.

1) Create a function to handle the drag event (of type [d3.event](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_event)):

```
function dragmove(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .style("top", ((d3.event.sourceEvent.pageY) - this.offsetHeight/2)+"px")
      .style("left", ((d3.event.sourceEvent.pageX) - this.offsetWidth/2)+"px")
}
```

2) Create drag behavior using the above function as handler:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragmove);
```

3) Bind it to an element or a set of elements using `.call` on a d3 selection:

```
d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("id", "draggable")
    .text("Drag me bro!")
    .call(drag)
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/HvkgN/2/

Here's the same example, [adapted for an svg text element](http://jsfiddle.net/HvkgN/4/):

```
function dragmove(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("y", d3.event.y)
      .attr("x", d3.event.x)
}

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragmove);

d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("height", 300)
    .attr("width", 300)
    .append("text")
        .attr("x", 150)
        .attr("y", 150)
        .attr("id", "draggable")
        .text("Drag me bro!")
        .call(drag)
```

Comment: Sorry that is not what i meant.. I have SVG Text Elements that i need to drag and they don't respond to .call(drag)

Comment: @chenninger Isn't this what the example here is doing?

Comment: @chenninger I updated the example for an svg text element! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Doesn't work in `d3` `version 4` and higher versions

Answer (score 2):

A better-looking way to add dragging to an SVG element is to use a translate transform that moves the draggable element around.  Couple this with a drag event handler that uses d3.event.dx and d3.event.dy to monitor the mouse's movement.

```
var transX = 0;
var transY = 0;
var theElement = d3.select('svg#xyz text.blahblah').attr('transform', "translate(" + transX + ", " + transY + ")");

var repositionElement = function(data) {
    transX += d3.event.dx;
    transY += d3.event.dy;
    theElement.attr('transform', "translate(" + transX + ", " + transY + ")");
};

var addDragging = function (element) {
    element.call(d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', repositionElement));
};

addDragging(theElement);
```

Also, unlike changing x/y directly, this technique can be used to make an entire `<g>` group draggable, so when the user clicks and drags any part of the group, the whole group moves!